# CrashlyticsCore: Expected method missing: registerOnMeasurementEventListener

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I've set up Crashlytics for Android adding the dependencies in the gradle files. I use `Crashlytics.logException(exception);` to log exceptions. Crashlytics got activated in the Firebase console after the app threw an Exception on purpose to try things out, but no event was detected and no log appeared, so the console shows 0 crashes. In the same time the LogCat shows the following:

```
I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.6.1.23
I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
W/CrashlyticsCore: Expected method missing: registerOnMeasurementEventListener
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: parameter type is null
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:656)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:626)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultAppMeasurementEventListenerRegistrar.invoke(DefaultAppMeasurementEventListenerRegistrar.java:89)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultAppMeasurementEventListenerRegistrar.register(DefaultAppMeasurementEventListenerRegistrar.java:54)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.registerAnalyticsEventListener(CrashlyticsController.java:1574)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.doInBackground(CrashlyticsCore.java:320)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.doInBackground(CrashlyticsCore.java:44)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 5ABA789603A5-0001-7C52-7AF6D12C00C8
```

Why is the `registerOnMeasurementEventListener` method missing; I have only a default proguard-rules.pro file with the following:

**UPDATED:**

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static int d(...);
}

############ Crashlytics ################################
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

Comment: Facing same issue!

Comment: Have you find the solution for this? I'm just facing the exact same problem right now

Answer (score 11):

Expanding on what several have already said before, it is sufficient to add this to you proguard.cfg:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$OnEventListener { *; }
```

The only reason this is necessary is that Fabric references these two classes by reflection and proguard doesn't detect that.

Answer (score 2):

Add to your proguard-rules.pro

```
 ############ Crashlytics ################################
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Comment: I've added these lines to the proguard file, but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: Try to remove `yourApp/build` and `yourApp/app/build` and rebuild all app.

Comment: I rebuilt several times. The warning doesn't go away, but there could actually be another problem for not receiving the logs in the console. Finally I got one, although the warning is still present.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and I just find the solution...
So, looking at the stacktrace, it says the problem is that the method `registerOnMeasurementEventListener` is not found, right? But it doesn't say where.

Looking at the decompiled code for that class `DefaultAppMeasurementEventListenerRegistrar`. It shows that the method is being called from the class:

```
Class onEventListenerClass = this.getClass("com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$OnEventListener");
```

So, I just added the extra following to the proguard file:

```
-keep class com.google.android.** { *; }
```

And it worked, the warning is gone. I guess I could have added the specific class instead of all under `com.google.android` but my thought process was: I might not want to touch any Android classes as this same problem might present for other libraries or other code.

Anyway, I hope this help you or it might help some other people having the same issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem today.
I solved it adding the lines below:

```html
-keep class com.google.android.gms.measurement.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.measurement.**
```

Probably it could be related to the class DefaultAppMeasurementEventListenerRegistrar (method register(), line 37)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue when I was integrating Crashlytics into a project where I was using firebase crash reporting tool.

I had this line

```
FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("NonFatal: Network Failure");
```

When I replaced it with

```
Crashlytics.log("NonFatal: Network Failure noticed ");
```

This exception was no longer thrown. 
The above log was integrated with Timber logging.

```
Timber.plant(...);
```